# Ply Custom Syntax Errors

Tags: python, parsing, syntax, ply

I'm creating a parser using PLY in Python. Everything's going well so far but the problem is, I don't know how to use a custom p_error for each statement. I currently have a p_error: statement at the bottom of the parser file that prints "Syntax error" for every kind of error in the program. But how could I make it say Syntax error when it's a syntax error and some other kind of error when it's not a syntax error?

Comment: You want to catch `Syntax Error` ?

Comment: @Lafada I'd like to display specific errors depending on what is wrong with the users program. At the moment the parser says every error is a syntax error.